# How to use filter method correctly in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter

My service retrieves a list of the ExceptionReportSessionData interface. One session can have many or no ReportFiles associated with it. What I cannot figure out how to do is if the user selects a Session from the first drop down box, I only want them to see the ReportFiles in the second drop down box that are associated with that session.

Here is what I currently have:

component.ts:

```
export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {

  public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[] = [];
  currentSession: ExceptionReportSessionData = null;
  selectedReport: string;
  index: number;


  constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {
  }

  private async getExceptionReportSessionData(): Promise<void> {
    this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData()
      .then(
        data => {
          this.sessionData = data;
          console.log(this.sessionData)
        });
  }


  sessionDataChange(value: any) {
    this.index = value.target.selectedIndex;
    this.currentSession = this.sessionData[value.target.selectedIndex];
    // this.currentSession = value;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getExceptionReportSessionData(); 
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="input-group">
    <h4>Session: </h4>
    <select [(ngModel)]='currentSession'
            class="custom-select form-control-sm"
            (change)='sessionDataChange($event)'
            id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option [value]="null">Select session...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let session of sessionData" [value]='session'>
        {{session.sessionName}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf='currentSession' class="input-group">
    <h4>Report Date: </h4>
    <select [(ngModel)]='selectedReport' class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option [value]="null">Select report...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let report of currentSession.ReportFiles"
              [value]="report">
        {{report}}
      </option>

    </select>
  </div>
```

Interface.ts:

```
export interface ExceptionReportSessionData {
  SessionName: string,
  ReportFiles: Array<string>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a stackblitz that solves your problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/filtering-field-problem).

The solution was to keep track of the session that was currently selected in the first `<select>` tag and fill in the reports from the currently selected session into the second `select` tag.

But there were a few errors in your code and I addressed them below:

In regular HTML, we can't set an object type to be the value of an `option`. It will automatically convert the object to `"[object Object]"` for the `<option>` value. To solve this, I had Angular listen to a selection event on your first `select` tag, grabbed the index of the select option and matched it back to that 
`ExceptionReportSessionData` array position in the component (I created some dummy data).

To have Angular listen to selection events:

**HTML**:

```
<select (change) = "func($event.target.selectedIndex)">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**TypeScript**

```
func(index: number) {
  // index of the selected option 
}
```

Secondly, I hid the second  using *ngIf until a session was selected (and set to `currentSession`) . This would prevent the HTML from throwing any errors about trying to access undefined fields when `currentSession` isn't defined.

Finally, in the section , I simply iterated through the `reports` using `*ngFor` and set the value of the . We can successfully do this now since the each element of the `reports` key is a string.

Comment: Updated question with your implementation